# Automatically Geocoding Location entries in a Google Fusion Table

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-fusion-tables

I am building a web app where users can search for places via the Google Maps API and then enter those places locations (Lat, Lng) in a Google Fusion table. Those location entries are then displayed on a different "Navigation" map.

My problem is that in order for the location entry to be displayed on the "Navigation" map is must be geocoded. Thus far the only way I can see to do geocode a fusion table entry is maunally on the file menu of my Fusion Tables account. Can any one suggest away to automate this. Preferably in JavaScript before the location is entered into the fusion table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/), but you need to be mindful of the [Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html), which has restrictions around storage of data received from the API.

Comment: What part of the Geocoded response should I add to the fusion table? I am already adding Lat, Lng coordinates and they still come up highlighted yellow in the table indicating that they have not been geocoded.

Comment: The problem I was having was that the way I was parsing coordinates put parenthesis around them and the fusion table wasn't recognizing it as a coordinate. Coordinates inserted into a fusion table should be of the form "x,y" NOT "(x,y)"...with out the quotes of course.